# What is a good way to subclass python's list or UserList so I can change the underlying data but use the built-in sort?

Tags: python-3.x

Lets say I want to create a list type subclass CaesarList, such that all element access are shifted by some amount (hardcoded in the class, not a parameter.  stupid yes, but this is just an example).

That is, if I have it hardcoded to +2,

```
   arr = CaesarList()
   arr.extend([1,2,3,4,5])
```

then `arr[2] == 5`, `arr[0]==3`.  So I can do that part easily by overriding `__getitem__`.  Or I want to make it a 2d array, or some other nonsense, I can override `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`.  But I want to be able to take advantage of built in sort.  How do I go about creating a UserList or list compatible subclass that will really perform `arr.sort()`?

Comment: Doesn't `arr.sort()` already work? Because the transformation you're applying to each element is order-preserving anyway. If not, you could override `sort` to call the superclass's `sort` method with `key=self.__getitem__`. I really doubt it's necessary to write a subclass of `list` to solve your actual problem, though.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. This was a random example I pull straight out of the void, so probably not great. My actual problem I wanted to solve WAS to subclass list and use the built-in .sort(). Out of curiosity and a desire to be maximally lazy while being maximally productive. But some irl friends pointed out that the builtin .sort of list is optimized c code that does not use the __ methods to access the underlying data. So, if I wanted to do something analogous, I would need to do my index translation there. And that's more than I wanted to do, which is to write a minimal amount in python.

Answer (score 0):

If you override the `__lt__` function in your class it should work. [Relevant docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__)

Answer (score 0):

I should have known this, but this is not doable to my requirements.  `.sort()` is optimized c code, and so it doesn't interact with the data using `__getItem__`, `__setItem__`.  I can write my own sort in the class, and it would work. I can also SORT of (ha) get `sorted` to work, but that's neither in-place nor does it preserve the underlying data structure, it'll output a regular list.  the only other option is to write some c, and at that point it moves beyond what I wanted to do, as the whole point was simple changes in python.